# local apt repo update own software

Tags: apt, repo

I've created a local apt repo on apache2 using this structure:

```
mkdir -p /var/www/html/repo/pool/main/

cp /home/xxx.deb /var/www/html/repo/pool/main/.

mkdir -p /var/www/html/repo/dists/focal/main/binary-amd64

cd /var/www/html/repo

dpkg-scanpackages --multiversion --arch amd64 pool/ > dists/focal/main/binary-amd64/Packages

cat dists/focal/main/binary-amd64/Packages | gzip -9 > dists/focal/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz
```

Made a release, signed the release in /var/www/html/repo/dists/focal

Added rule in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gmss.list

After all this I can install my debs on this repository, however when I add a new version of my software in the pool and make a new package file and I do:

```
apt update

apt install softwarepkg
```

It says that the latest version is already installed.
How can I get this to update to the latest version op my software?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try running `apt clean` to clear the cache, which may have the older version of your package.